# Points to Polygon in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, software-recommendations, web-gis

Is there a method to join points together to create a polygon in OpenLayers or other WebGIS platforms?

I have been searching for some while and I have found that dropzone.js can allow me to upload data to my SQL table as points which can be displayed but I cannot find anything that carries out a similar method like QGIS or ArcGIS "Points to Polygon".